# How to fix NaN values in concatenated multiple tables in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, data-science, data-analysis

I am using Jupyter Notedbook. I have concatenated multiple tables. When I run the head() command I am not able to see the values in age and gender columns in a table rather than it's showing me NaN values against each user_id.

The following image_1 shows us the output when I concatenated the different two tables
[image: In this Image_1 you can see I have the values in age and gender column but later on when I try to access the output of the tables by using head() command I am not able to see those values. I have attached another image_2. Where you can see it]

[image: Image_2]

How can I sort it out this issue or suggest me another way to conatenate tables where I can see all of the table values?
or do I need to access tables separeately and apply operations on different tables?

I am expecting to get the values in age and gender table rather than NaN values.

When I use these tables separately. It shows correct results but I have a big data problem so I need to concatenate the tables to access each of the feature column. In the end, I can apply operations on concatenated table features.

Comment: hey Haseeb, you should provide the source tables, the expected resulting table and the code you use to concatenate them. To make it easier it would be nice if you additionally add the source tables in python code: eg. pd.DataFrame([[1,1],[2,2], [3,3]], columns=["Col1, Col2"])

Comment: I am going to share a dataset source with you. Could you please check it? Why I am getting the problem or what's the problem?
https://github.com/HaseebTariq7/Data_analysis_dataset

Answer (score 2):

I have been testing your problem with the two csv's of your Github.

First of all I loaded the two tables as 'df1' and 'df2', importing the pandas library.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/HaseebTariq7/Data_analysis_dataset/main/data_1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/HaseebTariq7/Data_analysis_dataset/main/data_2.csv')
```

Then, using the pandas library, you can merge both dataframes choosing the connection column, in this case, 'user_id'.

```
final_df= pd.merge(df1, df2,on='user_id')
```

Finally we have the 'final_df' with all the information of both tables and without NaN's.

Comment: Many Thanks, it's working perfectly but I want to know one more thing. If I have multiple datasets like hundred of datasets. Then how can I do it?
The above method is good for few datasets but not good approach if we have hundred of datasets. Please suggest another method for couple of datasets.

Comment: For a great number of datasets, I would use another software instead of Python, as SQL or similar.

Comment: Could you please share that method?

Comment: I can share some examples of queries for SQL [here](https://www.sqlshack.com/learn-sql-join-multiple-tables/) but you should have some knowledge of MySQL to understand it.

Comment: Dear Haseeb if the post has been useful could you accept it as a correct answer?